# low latency sounds on key presses

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer

I am trying to write an application(I'm a gui first timer) for my son, he has autism. There is a video player in the top half and a text entry area in the bottom. When letters are typed sounds are produced to mimic the words in the video.

There have been other posts on this site in regard to playing sounds on key presses, using gstreamer as a system call. I have also tried libcanberra but both seem to have significant delays between sounds. I can write the app in python or C but will likely do at least some of it in C.

I also want to mention that the video portion is being played by gstreamer. I tried to create two instances of gstreamer, to avoid expensive system calls but the audio instance seemed to kill the app when called.

If anyone has any tips on creating faster responding sounds I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Quick comment to answer another of your questions that was closed: Terminals send and receive characters.

Normally, terminals just display the characters they receive.  When terminals printed to rolls of paper, that was really all they could do.  Special characters, called control characters, weren't displayed: instead they caused the terminals printer carriage to return to the start of the line, or to feed some paper, or to backspace.

Display terminals define special sequences of characters, called 'Escape Sequences' because they usually begin with the 'Esc' character.

Comment: When they receive an escape sequence, the terminals interpret it as a command for some other function, like moving the cursor to a specific position on the screen, or changing the text displayed in a section of the screen to reverse-video.

Each terminal brand would define its own set of escape sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload a raw audio sample directly to PulseAudio so there will be no decoding and (perhaps save) extra switches by using the following function from Canberra:

http://developer.gnome.org/libcanberra/unstable/libcanberra-canberra.html#ca-context-cache

The next ca_context_play() will use it.

However, the biggest problem you'll encounter with this scenario (with simultaneous video playback) is that the audio device might be configured with large latency with PulseAudio (up to 1/2s or more for normal playback). It may be reasonable to file a bug to libcanberra to support a LOW_LATENCY flag, as it currently doesn't attempt to minimize delay for sound events afaik. That would be great to have.

GStreamer pulsesink could probably get low latency too (it has some properties for that), but I am afraid it won't be as lightweight as libcanberra, and you won't be able to cache a sample for instance. Ideally, GStreamer could also learn to cache samples, or pre-fill PulseAudio...

Comment: I just want to mention a few things in case someone else stumbles on this thread later. First off, you can have two instances of gstreamer, there was a massive error in my code. Second I was able to produce the low latency sounds by recording them all in one recording and then seeking back and forth to them and setting gstreamer to pause after each sound. Thanks again to elmarco for posting.